# vector error when more then 10 digits in input

Tags: vector, boolean

You write in a random number and the code is supposed to work out how many unique numbers you put in. Example 5545 would give out 2 as answer. This works up to 10 digits, if I put in more digits I get a error message.. Why?

```
import java.util.Random;

import se.lth.cs.window.SimpleWindow;
import se.lth.cs.p.ovn.turtle.Turtle;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class p5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int apa=0;
    System.out.println("ange tal");
    int tal = scan.nextInt();
    boolean hej [] = new boolean[10];
    if(tal==0){
        hej[0]=true;
        System.out.println("awejawejwaejae");

    }
    while(tal>0){
    int z = tal%10;
    hej[z]=true;
    tal=tal/10;
    }



    for(int k=0; k<10; k++)
    if(hej[k]==true){
    apa++;
    }
    System.out.println(apa);
    for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
        System.out.println(hej[k]);
    }


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's `int` type is a 32-bit signed integer, i.e. it holds values from `-2^31` to `2^31 - 1`.
The maximum value `2^31 - 1` is `~2.14 * 10^10`, i.e. has 10 digits. If your number is larger than this it will become negative, which will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as `tal%10` will be negative.

You can use a `long` instead of an `int` (which has a maximum value of `~9.2 * 10^18`), or use BigDecimal for arbitrarily large numbers, or operate on the number as a string (i.e. don't parse it at all) to circumvent this issue.